# How do I combine two sets of multiple columns based with a reference column in Excel?

Tags: excel, sorting, mapping

Column F to K maps a numeric ID to a player and biographical info. And, column A to C contains ranking info of each player.

How can I rearrange column F to K to match the row values in column C?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, write title for cell L = `"Date"` and cell K1 = `"Rank"`

Cell L2 = "`=INDEX($A$2:$B$9999, MATCH(F2,$C$2:$C$9999,0),1)`"

Cell K2 = "`=INDEX($A$2:$B$9999, MATCH(F2,$C$2:$C$9999,0),2)`"

Then you can fill the rest of the down... for row 3 change F2 to F3 and so on.

Comment: Thank you! BTW, how do I update the row in the function automatically?

Comment: You can check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fill-a-formula-down-into-adjacent-cells-041edfe2-05bc-40e6-b933-ef48c3f308c6 or the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcA9MMskIRg

Comment: Don't forget to select this one as an answer